# Merge several mySQL databases with equivalent structure

Tags: php, mysql, database, merge

I would like write a php script that merges several databases, and I would like to be sure of how to go around it before I start anything.

I have 4 databases which have the same structure and almost same data. I want to merge them without any duplicate entry while preserving (or re-linking) the foreign keys.

For example there is a `db1.product` table which is almost the same as `db2.products` so I think I would have to use `LIKE` comparison on `name` and `description` columns to be sure that I only insert new rows. But then, when merging the `orders` table I have to make sure that the `productID` still indicates the right product.

So I thought of 2 solutions :

1. Either I use for each table `insert into db1.x as select * from db2.x` and then make new links and check for duplicate using triggers.
2. Either I delete duplicate entries and update new foreign keys (after having dropped constraints) and then insert row into the main database.
3. Just heard of MySQL Data Compare and Toad for mySQL, could they help me to merge tables ?

Could someone indicate to me what should be the right solution ?

sorry for my english and thank you !

Answer (score 0):

First thing is how are you determining whether products are the same? You mentioned LIKE comparison on name and description. You need to establish a rule what says that product is one and the same in your db1, db2 and so on.

However, let's assume that product's name and description are the attributes that define it.

`ALTER TABLE products ADD UNIQUE('name', 'description');`

Run this on all of your databases.

After you've done that, select one of the databases you wish to import into and run the following query:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO db1.products SELECT * FROM db2.products;`

Repeat for the remaining databases.

Naturally, this all fails if you can't determine how you're going to compare the products.
Note: never use reserved words for your column names such as word "name".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, good luck with this - sounds like a tricky job.

Secondly, I wouldn't do this with PHP - I'd write SQL to do the work, assuming this is a one-off migration task and not a recurring task.

As an approach, I would do the following.

1. Create a database with the schema you want - it sounds like each of your 4 databases have small variations in the schema. Just create the schema for now, don't worry about the data.
2. Create a "working" database, with the same schema, but with columns for "old" primary keys. For instance:

   table ORDER
   order_id int primary key auto increment
   old_order_id int not null
   ...other columns...

   table ORDER_LINE
   order_line_id int primary key auto increment
   old_order_line_id int not null
   order_id int foreign key
   ...other columns...
3. Table by table, Insert into your working database from your first source database. Let the primary keys auto_increment, but put the original primary key into the "old_" column. 
   For instance:

   insert into workingdb.orders
   select null, order_id, ....other columns...
   from db1.orders

Where you have a foreign key, populate it by finding the record in the old_ column.
For instance:

```
insert into workingdb.order_line
select null, ol.order_line_id, o.order_id
from   db1.order_line ol, 
       workingdb.order
where  ol.order_id = o.old_order_id
```

1. Rinse and repeat for the other databases.
2. Finally, copy the data from your working database into the "proper" database. This is optional - it may help to retain the old IDs for lookups etc.